# Aggregation function error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
select avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) 
from(select Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff from ras)as s;
```

I am going somewhere wrong where i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: this is why you always need to format your queries :)

Comment: This isn't an "aggregation function error". This is a simple syntax error, and unbalanced (unmatched) close paren. This question won't be of any benefit to the Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a `)` too much in your subquery

```
select avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) 
from
(
  select Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview) as eff 
  from ras
)as s;
```

Comment: Formatting matters :-)

Comment: @johnRuddell: Please only edit code of other users if ít is unformatted or obviously formatted wrong. Not because **you** like it better.

Comment: @juergend it was unformatted... the select statements should be on a new line.. the OP messed up because of a missing ) when it wasn't formatted

Comment: My code was formatted and I rolled it back to how it was and how I like it to stay.